# Accessing Grunt output in Gruntfile.js

Tags: gruntjs

In short, what I'm wondering is if there is a way to take Grunt output and access it within my Gruntfile so as to be able to make an http POST request.

In long form: I want to take data from running tests with Grunt (karma and jshint) and utilise whether karma and jshint passed or failed in the post request.  Is it possible to do this easily?  Or would I need to do something like write Grunt's output to a file, parse that, and then use something like grunt.file to read in the data to my Gruntfile?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Grunt uses methods from [grunt.log](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.log) object for writing log messages. As you can see in the [sources](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/blob/58290198e41c58e50dd2e661442bcab50ec1e292/lib/grunt.js#L30), `grunt.log` now implemented in a separate module `grunt-legacy-log`. So anyway, we can redefine these methods from inside Gruntfile to perform any actions with logs we want.

Firstly, install `grunt-legacy-log` through npm:

```
npm install grunt-legacy-log
```

Then, redefine `grunt.log` like this:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
  var Log = require('grunt-legacy-log').Log;
  var log = new Log({grunt: grunt});

  function LogExtended() {
    for (var methodName in log) {
      if (typeof log[methodName] === 'function') {
        this[methodName] = (function (methodName) {
          return function () {
            var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);

            // Filter methods yourself here to collect data
            // and perform any actions like POST to server
            console.log(methodName, args);

            // This will call original grunt.log method
            return log[methodName].apply(log, args);
          }
        }(methodName));
      }
    }
  }
  LogExtended.prototype = log;

  grunt.log = new LogExtended();

  grunt.initConfig({ .. });
};
```

That's it. Hope you can collect needed data.